# How could I ensure that images rated in one session do not show up again for the user to rate?

Tags: php, image, session, random

Images are displayed randomly for users to rate.

However, the way I have it set up currently, rows (images from the database) are randomly loaded with rand(), so some of these images may be displayed again, even if the user has already rated them.

There is no user registration, so I can't check against that.

Is there a way to ensure that for just that particular session, if an image is rated, it will not be displayed again?

Answer (score 1):

Save shown image in session array or in database. DB is the most reliable

Comment: @oxo: $_SESSION['viewed_images'][$image_id] = true;

Answer (score 1):

Assign each user a temporary random identifier. You can store the identifier in either a cookie or a component in the URL. If you use a form, you can store it in a hidden field in the form. So as a user goes from page to page, the identifier stays the same.

Then you can store in a database which images the user has already rated. If you randomly generate an image they have already seen, just generate a new one.

The only problem with this is it gets painful once the user has seen a significant fraction of the images. There are a few solutions to this, but simplest is probably just to empty the records for the user and let them start over.

You can avoid having separate records by just searching if that identifier has already submitted a rating for that image.

Comment: I'm trying to do it such that the user does not see the previous 100 images he has rated. Is it possible to set up a session array with SplFixedArray(100)?

Comment: You can do it in the browser with JavaScript if you want.

Answer (score 1):

If you mean to save the rated images list only for the current session, i.e. till the browser of the user is open. You can store it in the PHP Session Object. Look at [PHP Sessions](http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.session.php) on php.net

But if you want to remember it for the users, so that even on browser restart the same images are not shown again, then you will need to store the list of previously rated images in a database along with a persistent cookie with an id.